# Nifi monitor - can I use jmx port to monitor Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to monitor Nifi using Splunk monitoring tool. I need to send JMX metrics to splunk index, so that it processes data. is there a way to monitor nifi using JMX Port ?
FYI: I am not looking for rest API /rest endpoint

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you set the System property `com.sun.management.jmxremote.port` in `$NIFI_HOME/conf/bootstrap.conf` as described in [Monitoring and Management Using JMX Technology](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html), you can connect to this port with a remote monitoring client.

To monitor locally with `jconsole`, you don't need to do anything; just start Apace NiFi as normal and select the "org.apache.nifi.NiFi" process when presented with the list of running processes in JConsole.

It is strongly recommended to secure your monitoring connection with TLS and use a strong authentication mechanism like client certificates to ensure the application is safe.